# Current Rating of JST connector PER PIN

Tags: current

[image]

Hi,

I'm just wondering about the current rating of the JST-XH and JST-VH connectors PER pin. For example, in the XH connector above, **

- **it says 3A current rating, is that split between all pins or does
  that mean one pin can carry 3A?**

**

So in essence, if I dedicate two pins to VCC, then I could achieve 6A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's per pin, however I think you're talking about paralleling contacts to double the capacity.

The current will be more likely to share more-or-less evenly if your wires are at least 1ft (30cm) long (and at least roughly matched in length). That's 16m\$\Omega\$ for the AWG22 wire vs the 10-20m\$\Omega\$ contact resistance.

If you're anticipating possible high ambient temperatures, you might want to scale back the total current a bit to account for uneven sharing.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be better to parallel contacts or use twice the number of connectors? I guess it would depend on heat right? I'm assuming the PCB side of things wouldn't be so happy with that much power being concentrated at one connector.

Answer (score 2):

You may add currents per pin but the MAX ambient temp spec range reduces some unknown value due to increased self-heating.

E.g.  3A^2* 20 mOhm = 180mW so the pin contact temperature might rise 40'C but adjacent pin temp somewhat less.

Answer (score 1):

They mean per-pin.  Note that you must use 22ga. wire (largest size this takes) to get the highest current rating.