# Connector data sheet: meaning of "Current Rating ... 6 adjacent contacts"

Tags: datasheet, power-connector

What does a connector datasheet (such as page 2 of [this datasheet](http://suddendocs.samtec.com/productspecs/slh-tlh.pdf) ) mean by

> "Current Rating: 2.1 A (Gold plating, 6 adjacent contacts)"

Does it mean

- Each pin can handle 2.1 A each, when up to 6 adjacent contacts are carrying current? (so a total of 12.6 A per connector spread across 6 pins)
- Up to 6 adjacent contacts can carry a total of 2.1 A? (so 350 mA per contact)
- Up to 6 adjacent contacts can carry a total of 2.1 A out and 2.1 A back? (so 700 mA per contact)
- Something else?

(Related, but I suspect a slightly different question:
[Current Rating of JST connector PER PIN](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414333/current-rating-of-jst-connector-per-pin))

Answer (score 1):

Your first interpretation is correct. The contract resistance will generate a little heat and with 2.1 A per contact the middle ones will get hot.

Comment: actually: none of the above. That are the specs of an endurance test, not current ratings, as david interprets them. But I'd agree with your interpretation of the test description

Answer (score 1):

Those are the product test specifications. The actual product data says it's 2.1A per pin (but with 2 pins powered).